# NSight Monitor fails to start

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, nsight

I've installed NSight 2.1 RC1 with the correct (as posted in the release, 285.67) drivers.

I'm running Windows 7 64bit and have two cards, ATI (connected to display) and GTS 450 (Which I've seen that it's architecture GF106 is supported).

Every time I start the monitor (with "Run as administrator"), I see it for a short while (one to three seconds) in the task manager, then it disappears. I've looked with procmon, and the only thing fishy was some "buffer overflow" messages when reading some certificates (don't know if that is the problem, because it looks like it continues to run a bit afterwards).

I'm attaching the procmon trace if it helps.

Please help, I'm at a dead end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a member of the Nsight team at NVIDIA. Would you mind performing the following for me? This will generate a log that may gain us some insight into the issue.

In your %ProgramFiles(x86)%/NVIDIA Parallel Nsight Monitor 2.1/Common/Injection64 directory, execute the following command line statement: Nvda.Gpu.Configuration.Dump.100.exe gpu.txt /publictree

It will generate a file called gpu.txt.

To send that to me, go to: http://developer.nvidia.com/contact

Fill out your information, and select ParallelNsight-Support from the Category drop down. I'll see it and I'll contact you to receive that log.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi,

Using Jeff's advice to get the logs. I've noticed that I'm getting errors when the monitor tries to open port 8000 and fails. After doing some digging, I've found that one of my other programs was listening on that port. After changing its port to something else, the monitor worked.

Thanks Jeff for the quick reply.

Comment: Just to note for anyone who is seeing this question now. The contact URL listed above is no longer valid. To reach me, please email devtools-support at nvidia dot com. Thanks!